# Sencha touch and Phonegap, sencha app build error

Tags: cordova, extjs, ant, touch, compass

I've been trying to integrate `sencha` touch with `phonegap` for days now. But, I can't seem to understand how to fix this one particular error, it occurs every time I run the command.

`sencha app build native` or `sencha app build`

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFRrx.png)
[image]

Here are the lines mentioned in the error

1.C:\xampp\htdocs\NewSTest.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:286:

```
 <x-ant-call unless="skip.sass">
```

2.C:\xampp\htdocs\NewSTest.sencha\app\sass-impl.xml:299:

```
<x-run-if-true value="${enable.touch.themes}">
```

3.C:\xampp\htdocs\NewSTest.sencha\app\sass-impl.xml:305:

```
<x-compass-compile
                rubyPath="${build.ruby.path}"
                trace="${compass.compile.trace}"
                boring="${compass.compile.boring}"
                force="${compass.compile.force}"
                dir="${compass.sass.dir}"/>
```

P.S. - I have the following dependencies installed i.e
PhoneGap
SenchaCmd
Ant
JDK
ADT
Ruby
Compass

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to do a normal `production` build? Does the error occur with a production build as well?

Comment: Yes I have, it gives me the same error...